# Alt @decorators in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am using the [Alt](http://alt.js.org/) library (Flux implementation) with React-Native.  I really like the 'alt/utils/decorators' and 'alt/utils/connectToStores' but I cannot use these @decorators because the RN/Babel config doesn't seem to support it.

I'm definitely not well versed in Babel (or RN for that matter) so I am in need of help configuring RN/Babel to work with @decorators.

How can I use the Alt library's @decorators with React-Native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel 6 currently intends for the `transform-decorators` to support the upcoming change to the decorators proposal, which will make it behave quite differently from the existing one.

If you need decorators in Babel 6 with the same semantics as decorators in Babel 5, your best option is to use [babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  How do I use that transform with React-Native?  (sorry, if this is a dumb/obvious question)

Comment: That I don't know off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: Here's how to implement this suggestion/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34311400/941058

Comment: note: remember to close `terminal` and run build again.

Answer (score 1):

See 0.16 release notes:

> Decorators won't work until [T2645](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2645) lands in Babel.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/breaking-changes.md

Once this is fixed then they should begin working.

Comment: As mentioned in that bug, https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy be all you need.

Comment: Oh nice, must have missed that.