# Run a custom Babel transform with React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I need to use `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` with React-Native to enable @decorators.  How does one configure React-Native / Babel to make this possible?

This is related to my previous question about how to get @decorators working in React-Native: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34271636/941058

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Use official Babel presets

Install the official [Babel presets for React Native applications](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset):

```
npm i babel-preset-react-native --save-dev
```

Edit your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

## Prior RN v21.0: Extend the original .babelrc from react-native

To avoid manipulating files in the `node_modules` directory, you should [extend](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) the original `.babelrc`.

By keeping your dependencies clean, there won't be any issues with upgrades or sharing the project.

```
{
    "extends": "react-native/packager/react-packager/.babelrc",
}
```

Comment: on RN 0.21, that file is no longer there. It is now called 
react-native/packager/react-packager/rn-babelrc.json

Comment: is this still current as of 0.24.1?

Comment: @Chris It should be.

Answer (score 3):

You would install the plugin at your projects root level then add the plugin to the .babelrc in node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/.babelrc

The issue with this work around to using @decorators is if you are working on a team for the app every developer will need to make the change to .babelrc since node_modules should not be checked into source.

Answer (score 2):

As of Jan 2016, you can simply create a `.babelrc` file near `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` that looks like:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alon Gubkin - It hasn't been as easy as you suggested.  I am getting an error which I think is related to having a .babelrc in both my root AND the react-native/packager/react-packager path.  Any thoughts?  "Method has decorators, put the decorators plugin before the classes one."

Comment: @kingdango Did you make any changes to their .babelrc? If yes, try to use their original .babelrc file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add it to your .babelrc in your react native folder in your node_modules folder.

This file:
react-native/packager/react-packager/.babelrc.

Put it before the syntax-class-properties.

You also appear to need a .babelrc at the root level like suggested below.

```
    {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators"
      ]
    }
```